# Updates which include auto increment column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and I would like to update a table which would include an auto number column id. I know it might something very simple but I have done something like this;

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  SEQ_ID
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10

update trk2
set (id, track_id, track_point) =
           (select nextval('seq_id'), trk1.track_fid, trk1.wkb_geometry
              from track_points_1 as trk1
             where track_fid = 0)
```

The thing is that it is giving me the following error (*code reformatted*):

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 3: set (id, track_id, track_point)=(select nextval('seq_id'), t...
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: still giving me the same error

Comment: You shouldn't do this. If you are updating an existing row, the id/primary key _should_not_change_. If you want a new id, you should insert a new row and delete the old one. Primary keys should not change, that breaks the whole relational algebra.

Comment: It isn't true that primary keys should never change. But, I can't think of a situation where it would make sense to change a synthetic primary key (like one generated from a sequence).

Comment: You don't have a where clause on the outer query. Which means that **each and every row** in trk2 will get the values retrieved by the subquery. And that is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is broken in several places. It could look something like this:

```
UPDATE trk2
SET   (id, track_id, track_point) = 
      (next_id, x.track_fid, x.wkb_geometry)
FROM  (
   SELECT id
         ,nextval('seq_id') AS next_id
         ,track_fid
         ,wkb_geometry
   FROM   track_points_1
   WHERE  track_fid = 0
   ) x
WHERE  trk2.id = x.id;  -- adapt to your case
```

Or *simpler* (preferable syntax):

```
UPDATE trk2
SET   (id, track_id, track_point) = 
      (nextval('seq_id'), x.track_fid, x.wkb_geometry)
FROM   track_points_1 x
WHERE  x.track_fid = 0
AND    trk2.id = x.id;   -- adapt to your case
```

#### Major points:

- An `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` clause only makes sense if you really need to change each and every row in the table. Else it is wrong or at least sub-optimal.

  When you retrieve values from another table, you get a `CROSS JOIN` between target and source if you don't add a `WHERE` clause connecting target with source - meaning that every row of the target table will be updated with every row in the source table. This can take a very long time and lead to arbitrary results. The last `UPDATE` wins. In short: this is almost always complete nonsense and extremely expensive at that.

  In my example I link target and source by the `id` column. You have to replace that with whatever fits in your case.
- You *can* assign multiple values in one `SET` clause in an `UPDATE`, but you can only return a single value from a correlated subselect expression. Therefore, it is strictly not possible to have a subselect in a `SET` clause with multiple values.
- Your initial syntax error comes from a missing pair of parenthesis around your subselect. But adding that only reveals the error mentioned above.
- Depending on what you are after, you would include `nextval('seq_id')` in the subquery or in the `SET` clause directly. This can lead to very different results, especially when you have rows in the subquery that are not used in the `UPDATE`.

  I placed it in the `SET` clause because I suspect, that's what you want. The sequence of rows is still arbitrary. If you want more control over which numbers are assigned, you need to define what you want and then take a different route.

Answer (score 1):

Tyler Eaves is correct, **this action is not advisable**.

However, if you insist, this may help:

Once you have a sequence on a column you don't have to call `nextval()` in the `SET` statement. Just leave it out and the column will auto-increment.

```
UPDATE
    trk2
SET 
    (
        track_id = [track_id Value],
        track_point = [track_point Value]
    )
```

or, include it and set it to `default` or `null`

```
UPDATE
    trk2
SET 
    (
        id = default,
        track_id = [track_id Value],
        track_point = [track_point Value]
    )
```

Using your example:

```
UPDATE
    trk2
SET 
    (
        track_id, 
        track_point
    ) = (
        SELECT 
            trk1.track_fid,
            trk1.wkb_geometry
        FROM 
            track_points_1 AS trk1
        WHERE
            track_fid = 0
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a second set of parentheses on the RHS of the SET clause:

```
UPDATE trk2
SET (id, track_id, track_point) =
          ((SELECT nextval('seq_id'), trk1.track_fid, trk1.wkb_geometry
              FROM track_points_1 as trk1
             WHERE track_fid = 0));
```

The first set of parentheses matches the parentheses on the LHS of the SET clause.  The second set wraps up the sub-query for re-use.